# Turn Android TV Device into Public Media Player

Tags: media-player

I've got an Android TV device here and we want to use it in a public media display. We've got a few problems to solve:

1) Have the device turn on when it received power:
Looks like this would be a firmware thing and we're not going to solve it.

2) Load tons of media:
Solved: Device works great with a USB hard drive.

3) Have a Media Player app start on power up:
Solved: Using the Auto Start App

4) Find a media player that will:
a) Begin automatic playback of random media when started (no having to press play).
b) Allow really easy navigation of the USB Drive folders as albums when the only interface is a remote control.

Would really appreciate some help with finding the right media player app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closest thing I've been able to find is:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.burningthumb.premiervideokiosk&hl=en

Video Kiosk
Display a folder of videos, continuously and robustly in a loop.

Video Kiosk was designed with Android TV Sticks in mind (tested on MK808 and MK812) but also works with any Android device that you want to use to display a continuous series of looping videos.

Video Kiosk can used to run the big screen at a gym, shop, or anywhere where you need to run an unattended display, so you can be sure it will work simply and easily. The only thing other people need to know how to do is turn the TV on and off - Video Kiosk takes care of the rest.

Simply put your video files in a folder, launch Video Kiosk and pick the folder that contains the video. Optionally enable the launch at startup option so that when the device is (re)started, Video Kiosk automatically launches and starts playing video.